# Help bulkify salesforce invocable method (called from flow)

Tags: apex, invocable-method, bulkification

I have a very basic invocable action that is used by a flow to return the useraccess record if the user has edit rights (if not, the return would be a null list - barring sysadmin users of course).

I know this isn't fully bulkified though and I always struggle with that... would somebody mind pointing me in the right direction with the below?  I know I need to circle through the FlowInput list and have a feeling map might be needed but I am still such a novice I'm asking here!

Thanks in advance,
Ben.

```
public class CheckUserPermissions {

@InvocableMethod(label='Returns whether a given member has edit access on given record' description='Returns found recordaccess list if editaccess is true / zero-entry list if not')

public static List<List<UserRecordAccess>> CheckUserPermissionsOT(List<FlowInput> inputs) {
List<List<UserRecordAccess>> accessList = new List<List<UserRecordAccess>>();
List<UserRecordAccess> access_level = new List <UserRecordAccess>([Select RecordId from UserRecordAccess where RecordId = :inputs[0].recordId and UserId = :inputs[0].UserID and HasEditAccess=TRUE]);
accessList.add (access_level);
return accessList ;
}

public class FlowInput {

  @InvocableVariable(required=true)
  public Id userId;

  @InvocableVariable(required=true)
  public Id recordId; 
}
}
```

Comment: Hi @Ben, thanks for posting your question. Although it isn't fully bulkified, is there any use case for this method being called for multiple users within the same flow? What you have here is fine if there isn't.

Comment: @CallumMacErlich So I already have code that creates and stores a JSON string of opportunity team members on an op.  This is so I can have further code (!) that can recreate an opportunity team on change of owner if the user forgets to keep opportunity team.

This JSON string maintenance I've done in flow on add/edit of team member, and also delete.  HOWEVER... If the user triggering the delete doesn't have permission to edit, the opportunity team member delete is halted by Salesforce but only after the delete flow still processes the new JSON string, less the 'removed' record ... {cont}

Comment: {cont} @CallumMacErlich - so this small Apex Action will be used to test if the user actually has delete rights.  If not, I can stop my flow falsely recreating the JSON string (less the 'removed' team member), since SFDC will halt the delete.  As such, my JSON string of team members remains accurate.

<TL;DR> if I bulk removed a ton of team members this would fall over (albeit in real world... hugely unlikely).  So.... forget about truly bulkifying??

Answer (score 1):

IMHO best to bulkify now rather than leave a colleague in a mess a couple of years from now when a bulk case is needed.

Not too sure about your return signature  (why `List<List`?), but this is one way to use a single query albeit potentially querying unnecessary records but filtering those out in the results. (To return only the required records you'd need to use dynamic SOQL and that gets messier.)

```
public static List<UserRecordAccess> CheckUserPermissionsOT(List<FlowInput> inputs) {

    Set<Id> recordIds = new Set<Id>();
    Set<Id> userIds = new Set<Id>();
    for (FlowInput input : inputs) {
        recordIds.add(input.recordId);
        userIds.add(input.userId);
    }

    // This may query unnecessary records, but they will be filtered out later
    Map<String, UserRecordAccess> m = new Map<String>();
    for (UserRecordAccess access : [
        Select RecordId, UserId
        from UserRecordAccess
        where RecordId in :recordIds
        and UserId in :userIds
        and HasEditAccess=TRUE
    ]) {
        m.put(access.RecordId + access.UserId, access);
    }

    // Ensure the results are at same index as the inputs
    List<UserRecordAccess> results = new <UserRecordAccess>();
    for (FlowInput input : inputs) {
        UserRecordAccess access = m.get(input.recordId + input.userId);
        results.add(access);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Hi @Keith C - having issues with your above code... there are a few things I've tidied (return result should be results, 'List<UserRecordAccess> results = new <UserRecordAccess>();' missing List after new.

However, even after tidying that I'm getting ' Error: Invalid type argument count for Map: expected 2 but found 1'.. could you let me know if something else needs tidying in your code...  Thanks for your help!

Comment: Hi Ben, Didn't take too much care with this as you can tell... `Map<String, UserRecordAccess> m = new Map<String, UserRecordAccess>();` should fix the map error.

Comment: Appreciate the response @Keith.  However, I'm now hitting an issue I was working around - the special rules on SOQL query for User Record Access!

Firstly "Can select only RecordId, a Has*Access field, and MaxAccessLevel".  I can change this to just return RecordID.  But then I get "Can filter on only UserId = [single ID], either RecordId = [single ID] or RecordId IN [list of IDs], and Has*Access = true"

This is why I'm having to do this at all, since trying to do it in Flow fails due to the 'under the covers query' not actually conforming to the dev manual.

Comment: Apologies @Ben, didn't realise those restrictions exist. I'm not familiar enough to comment further I'm afraid.

Comment: No worries - appreciate your help anyway!  Given the rarity of this being bulk called I think I'll risk what I have until future needs demand otherwise.  Thanks!